# php rewrite url

Tags: php, url

Is it possible to have it so when a page is requested with a get parameter from an  link, say

```
www.mtsite.com?param=val
```

That the parameter stuff is hidden, without using post and JS?

Thanks

Comment: No, not without using SEF urls

Comment: Read about .htaccess file, how it works

Comment: I think you can't achieve this without the precious help of javascript.. try to make it more clear : is your goal to hide the parameter content ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could immediately set a cookie with the parameter after doing a redirect using:

```
 header('Location: http://www.mtsite.com');
```

I just read that the order has to be location redirect and then cookie set, so you'll want to make sure to do it in that order.

Then, when you catch the redirected page, get the cookie with that parameter and act appropriately (probably clearing the cookie in the process).